# Exclude specific files from zip command line

Tags: zip

I´m using zip to create a backup.

In the directory I´m processing, there are some files not intended to be included. My issue is that the filenames are named in this style:

```
abc-1 (excluded)

abc-2 (excluded)

abc-3.ini (included)
```

I don´t know how to specify the -x option in zip command line so that the first two files that have no extension are left out, and the third one is included.

I´ve tried

```
zip -r mybackup.zip mydir -x mydir/abc-*.
```

but it´s not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this worked:

```
zip -r mybackup.zip mydir -x mydir/abc-!(*.*)
```

...but only from the command line. When trying to include the command in a bash script, it didn´t work and I had to include the following line before:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

which enables the extended globbing.